# Multiple import statements at top of JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I have multiple (over 50) import statements at the top of my JavaScript file - like the following:

```
import marker1 from '../assets/markers/1.svg'
import marker2 from '../assets/markers/2.svg'
import marker3 from '../assets/markers/3.svg'
import marker4 from '../assets/markers/4.svg'
import marker5 from '../assets/markers/5.svg'
...
```

I don't believe this is the most efficient way to do this. Is there any way I can utilise an array or helper function to tidy this file up? Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could import it in one file like `marker.js` and then export a marker const on which you have added all your `markerX` svgs.

Then you could access it like this `marker.m1` when you import `marker.js`